# node.js require from parent folder

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following structure:

```
-- node_modules
-- websites
---- common
------- config.js
---- testing
------- test.js
```

Inside config I have some variables set, which are being exported using module.export.

I am trying to retrieve those variables when running `node test.js` from config.js using the following codes:

```
var configData = require('./common/config.js')
var configData = require('../common/config.js')
```

None of them work. What can I do to retrieve the data from the other folder?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

```
var configData = require('./../common/config.js');
```

1. `./` is `testing/`
2. `./../` is `websites/`
3. `./../common/` is `websites/common/`
4. `./../common/config.js` is `websites/common/config.js`

Comment: - Cannot find module

Comment: @PHPLover check now!

Answer (score 8):

from test.js:

```
const configData = require('../common/config');
```

You can safely omit `'.js'`.

As [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules) say:

> ## File Modules
>
> If the exact filename is not found, then Node.js will attempt to load the required filename with the added extensions: .js,
>   .json, and finally .node.
>
> **.js files are interpreted as JavaScript text files**, and .json files
>   are parsed as JSON text files. .node files are interpreted as compiled
>   addon modules loaded with dlopen.
>
> A required module prefixed with '/' is an absolute path to the file.
>   For example, require('/home/marco/foo.js') will load the file at
>   /home/marco/foo.js.
>
> **A required module prefixed with './' is relative to the file calling
>   require()**. That is, circle.js must be in the same directory as foo.js
>   for require('./circle') to find it.
>
> **Without a leading '/', './', or '../' to indicate a file, the module
>   must either be a core module or is loaded from a node_modules folder**.
>
> If the given path does not exist, require() will throw an Error with
>   its code property set to 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'.

More info about how `require()` work [here](http://fredkschott.com/post/2014/06/require-and-the-module-system/).

Comment: would you not need the `.js` extension?

Comment: Is not needed, and is automatically added from `require()` function during module loading.

Comment: gotcha.  Then how does this answer differ from what the OP has already tried and does not work?  Why would this work instead?

Comment: it still can't find the module calling from test.js ?

Comment: Removing the ".js" at the end of the file name does not answer the original question about importing a file in a parent directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
const cheerio = require('../node_modules/cheerio');
const request = require('../node_modules/request-promise');
const vl = require('../node_modules/validator');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.