# Folders as modules within folders as modules NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, circular-dependency

I am having trouble requiring from parent directories within NodeJS. I have read this post, but still couldn't figure it out.

[node.js require from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163049/node-js-require-from-parent-folder)

This is my file structure:

```
-- components/
    -- windows/
        -- index.js
    -- index.js
-- main.js
```

This is the code:

```
// /main.js
var components = require("./components")
components.windows.inner()

// /components/index.js
module.exports = {
    windows: require("./windows"),
    foo: "foo",
}

// /components/windows/index.js
var components = require("./..")
module.exports.inner = function() {
    console.log(components.foo)
}
```

When I run `main.js`, the `inner()` function prints `undefined`.

Why is it printing undefined? Shouldn't it print foo? Am I missing something about how Node works?

Comment: You have a circular dependency, that's what doesn't work. `require("./..")` returns an empty object, the export that gets later overwritten by the `module.exports =` assignment in `components/index.js`. Use dependency injection instead.

Comment: What is dependency injection? @Bergi

Answer (score 2):

You just built up a "circular dependency". `/components/windows/` requires `/components/`, which requires `/components/windows/`, which requires ...

To resolve those nevertheless, NodeJS initializes the exports to an empty object and rewrites them to the `exports` object after the module initialized. Therefore you can access `/components/windows` from inside `/components/` but not the other way round.

To remove the circular dependency,  move `foo` to another file that you require in both modules.

Comment: so, does it make sense to move `foo` into `windows/`?

Comment: @matt yes it would.