# Nodejs require from other folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, directory

I have the following structure of folders:

```
Proyecto

--pruebainventario
----models
------Usuarios.js

--SB
----src
------components
--------screens
----------Register.js
```

Inside Usuarios.js I have some variables set, which are being exported using module.exports = usuario.

I am trying to retrieve those variables when running node Register.js from Usuarios.js using the following codes:

```
var usuario = require('./../../../../pruebainventario/models/Usuarios.js')

var usuario = require('../../../../pruebainventario/models/Usuarios.js')
```

None of them work. What can I do to retrieve the data from the other folder? Please I really need make this. Thanks

Comment: first require is missing one dot in the begining and both the requires are missing closing single quote, is your code correct?

Comment: Yes, I forgot that when I put the code in the page, I'm following the answer from other question I found. Is this the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42163049/node-js-require-from-parent-folder/42163102# But that for some reason don't works for me

Comment: Well i know what it would be. But can you share the error you are getting?

Comment: Of curse, this is the error: Unable to resolve "./../../../../pruebainventario/models/Usuarios.js" from "src\components\screens\Register.js"              
Failed building JavaScript bundle.